# show toast if file exist into SD Card and also check for file size

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Trying to show toast if file already exist into SDCard, but seems condition not works for me

```
public void startDownload(View v) {

     if(hasAudio.equals("no"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MP3 not Available !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     else if(hasAudio.equals("yes"))             
        {
         File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "Audios", title + ".mp3" );
         if (file.exists()) 
         {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already downloaded !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else 
         {
            Uri uri=Uri.parse(download);
            mgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Audios", title + ".mp3"));

            v.setEnabled(false);
          }         
     }
}
```

whenever i do tap on button, its start downloading mp3, no matter already exist or not, but i want to show the toast if file already exist in SD Card

Comment: Are you sure you mean to check `getExternalCacheDir()` and not `getExternalFilesDir()`?

Comment: My suggestion is to check file size instead of just checking if it exists. So that even if download gets interrupted due to network failures(and corrupt file still exists), it works.

Comment: @SeshuVinay hey i agree with you, can you show me the way ?

Answer (score 0):

Then Why do you need else condition, remove it

```
public void startDownload(View v) {

 if(hasAudio.equals("no"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MP3 not Available !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 else if(hasAudio.equals("yes"))             
    {
     File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "Audios", title + ".mp3" );
     if (file.exists()) 
     {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already downloaded !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }else{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Exist !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }


 }
}
```

Comment: see this may be help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697650/check-if-file-exists-on-sd-card-on-android. also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817551/how-to-check-file-exist-or-not-and-if-not-create-a-new-file-in-sdcard-in-async-t