# android comparing text to save image and send via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

i make a project for hearing impaired people ,where two devices are connected **via bluetooth** , its already working sending and receiving messages but what i want is **when i type a text "hi"** in a **editext** and when i click the **send button** the display would be the picture  in a right(girl picture) but if that picture is not available display the second picture in left side(hand sign) , is this possible? can i compare the txt i type to the drawable folder image so that , that particular image will display?... .. [image]

```
 plz share ur idea....
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Then you will need the following:

   1. get the text (Hi) before displaying it, by `getText`
   2. check the availability of the image either you want it to be available in phone 1 or phone 2 by [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7817845/5873832)
2. Sure it is possible to send an image via Bluetooth, also you can code it as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180267/5873832)

Also my opinion is to upload the image to the firebase or let it with your application if you need it for much use

**Edit :** compairing file name with string that you want is like is

```
boolean fileExists =  new File("path/to/" + name + ".png").isFile();
```

where name if the chat message you want to compare and surely, that code occurs before the texts/images are displayed to the users

Comment: your most welcome, and if my opinion is good for you then I will wait for you to accept and vote up, also beware of opinion question and very detailed ones in order to not get vote down form users

Comment: sir, can i compare the "text" to a image file name in drawble? so that, that particular image will be display?

Comment: @Mr.abing_da_student Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)